# In what sense are C escape sequences "extensible"?

Tags: c, escaping

From Kernighan and Ritchie, page 8:

> Notice that \n represents only a single character. An escape sequence like
> \n provides a general and extensible mechanism for representing hard-to-type
> or invisible characters. Among the others that C provides are \t for tab, \b
> for backspace, " for the double quote, and \ for the backslash itself. There
> is a complete list in Section 2.3.

In what sense are C escape sequences "extensible"?

I tried various internet searches.

Comment: Also:  `\0`, `\xabc`, `\Xabc`, `\u1234`, `\U12345678` etc.

Answer (score 3):

I think it means that the standard could extend them in the future. For example, `\z` currently has no meaning, but it could in the future.

I don't know if it has happened in C, but Perl has extended this set numerous times. Both in strings literal and in regex patterns. One such escape is `\N{}`, which can be used in both to inject Unicode characters. For example, `\N{U+2660}` or `\N{BLACK SPADE SUIT}` can be used in lieu of character 0x2660 in literals.

Answer (score 1):

They are extensible in terms of specific implementations being able to define their own [conditional escape sequences](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.ccon#3.3). It doesn't mean that your own code can define arbitrary escape sequences.

Excerpts from the lexical conventions in the above link:

```
simple-escape-sequence-char: one of
    '  "  ?  \ a  b  f  n  r  t  v 

conditional-escape-sequence:
    \ conditional-escape-sequence-char

conditional-escape-sequence-char:
    any member of the basic character set that is not an octal-digit,
    a simple-escape-sequence-char, or the characters N, o, u, U, or x
```

I've cited a C++ reference here, but I believe the same is true in C.

Comment: C doesn't have conditional-escape-sequence, but other lower case letters following a backslash are reserved for future standardization, and other characters may be used in extensions. Some implementations (e.g. GCC) use `\e` for ASCII Escape, which is non-conforming.

Answer (score 1):

"*I tried various internet searches.*"

Did you try Wikipedia? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C

Scroll down to the example of `'\e'` being interpreted by **some** compilers to mean `ESC`.

Self-help is the best learning experience.